# Add two columns in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with this.
I want to add the second column in one dataframe to the second column in another dataframe based on index, and then put the result in a third dataframe. Ignore the time column

The Input:
Dataframe A

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2:30 | 5 |
| 2:35 | 9 |
| 2:40 | 300 |
| 2:45 | 200 |

Dataframe B

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 3:00 | 23 |
| 3:05 | 40 |
| 3:10 | 450 |
| 3:15 | 346 |

This is what I was thinking...

```
import pandas

dfa = pd.read_csv('T.csv')
dfb = pd.read_csv('H.csv')

s = dfa[dfa.columns[1]] + dfb[dfb.columns[1]]
```

At the moment, I'm getting this error (TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str)

Note: Please if you think there's another way to approach the problem I'm all ears.

Possible Output:

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 4:30 | 28 |
| 4:35 | 49 |
| 4:40 | 750 |
| 4:45 | 546 |